# How to add multiple pattern-based validators with parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Any idea how I can add multiple regex pattern validators in parsley.js? My code looks something like this:

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"
data-parsley-pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" 
data-parsley-pattern-message="error1"
data-parsley-pattern="\\s\\s" 
data-parsley-pattern-message="error2"
/>
```

When I run it, I only get the "error1" message for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible.

You can only register only once a specific validator in a field.

Either you work a bit more on your regexp to mix both requirements, either you create your own customs validators (with different names) that does each one its validation part.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Based on your REGEX pattern, it looks like you're trying to validate multiple zip/postal codes. That's not something you can do with REGEX, and you can't use multiple patterns with Parsley, but you can make a [custom Parsley validation](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html). Here's an example of one I wrote for validating both US (United States) Zip Code and Canada Postal Code. You don't need "custom validators with different names" like the accepted answer suggests.

**JavaScript**

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('validateZipcode', {
    validateString: function(value) {
        if (/^(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)$/.test(value)) { // United States Zip Code Format
            return true;
        } else if (/^([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z] [0-9][A-Za-z][0-9])$/.test(value)) { // Canada Postal Code Format
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    messages: {
        en: 'US format:<br>00000 or 00000-0000<hr class="mt-1 mb-1">Canada format:<br>A0A A0A'
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="hidden" for="zip-code">Zipcode</label>
<input
    required
    type="text"
    id="zip-code"
    placeholder="Zip Code"
    maxlength="10"
    data-parsley-trigger="change"
    data-parsley-required-message="Zipcode required"
    data-parsley-validate-zipcode=""
>
```

REGEX patterns pulled from: http://html5pattern.com/Postal_Codes